# Generating documentation for @BasePathAwareController annotated controller

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

I've found that documentation for the controllers annotated with `@RestController` is generated properly.

But when I use `@BasePathAwareController` annotation the documentation **is not generated**.

Do you know why is that?

Comment: This is because `spring-data-rest` isn't supported by springfox

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will have to look for some kind of workaround then.